# Still TDA2050 single supply circuit

Tags: audio, amplifier

1. I set power supply voltage=15v and the input is a sine wave. So, the maximum complete sine wave should swing +/-7.5v. If amplitude large than 7.5v, the waveform will change. For acoustic signal, will its pitch change?
2. If the pitch will be changed, why we give a limitation to amplifier?
3. If this as a real amplifier, as volume increase, the sound sounds strange. How to solve it?

[image: output]
[image: TDA2050]

Answer (score 1):

> If amplitude large than 7.5v, the waveform will change. For acoustic signal, will its pitch change?

The [pitch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_%28music%29) doesn't change when a signal is [clipped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_%28audio%29), you only get increased distortion.

> If this as a real amplifier, as volume increase, the sound sounds strange. How to solve it?

I assume you refer to the effect of increased distortion, lower the output power or increase the supply voltage to lower the distortion.

Comment: How to lower the output power?

Comment: the distortion has no effect to the acoustic signal?

Comment: @user33593 lower the input signal level, use a potentiometer or trimmer to form a voltage divider.   [Beginners' Guide to Potentiometers](http://sound.westhost.com/pots.htm#using)

Comment: @user33593 the distortion effects the signal, it adds harmonics but it doesn't change the pitch, refer to the link I have provided in the word clipped in my reply

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have another question. why this amplifier have a finite bandwidth? In op-amp, the bandwidth is infinite.

Comment: @user33593 You can take a look at http://www.ecircuitcenter.com/Circuits/op_bandwidth1/op_bandwidth1.htm